# How to place a google map/code inside a viewpager

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

Like the title says, I want to make a `ViewPager` which contains two sections:

1- a `Listview` (name of the places to go with PHP / MySQL / JSON)

2- and a `GoogleMap` with `Markers` depending of what you select in point 1

So, I have this code for a ListView and a second code for the GoogleMap with a location Button. I want to merge them in a ViewPager but I don't figure out how to make this possible. See my code below:

**google class:**

```
package com.bla;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

//extends FragmentActivity

public class google extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener  {


    Button btnShowLocation;

    // GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;
// GoogleMap googleMap;

LatLng myPosition;

private SupportMapFragment map;
private GoogleMap mMapView;


// add all necessary things

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google);

// if  Google Play Services are available then

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
          // SIRVE ... SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);


     /*   fm = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                 getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, fm);
         fragmentTransaction.commit();   */ 

          //  SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        map = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (map == null) {
            map = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, map).commit();
        }

      //   GoogleMap = mMapFragment.getMap();

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
      //  mMapView = fm.getMap();
        mMapView = map.getMap();
            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        mMapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
            // Getting latitude of the current location
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();

            // Getting longitude of the current location
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

             myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

             mMapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("Start"));

            }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**listview class:**

```
package com.example.mysqltest;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.example.mysqltest.R;



import com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator;

public class titlepager extends Activity {



// GoogleMap googleMap;

LatLng myPosition;

private SupportMapFragment map;
private GoogleMap mMapView;


        //these are the titles that will appear on the "tabs"
    final String[] page_titles = new String[]{"Home", "Me"};
    //this will go the description TextView
        final String[] desc = new String[]{
            "Aqui ira el listview ",
            "Aqui iraaa el mapa :D ",
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.title);

        //Instantiating the adapter
        GiloAdapter mAdapter = new GiloAdapter(this);

        //instantiate the Views
        ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        TabPageIndicator mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);


    private class GiloAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

        Context context;

        public GiloAdapter(Context c){
            this.context = c;
        }

        //This is the number of pages -- 5
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return page_titles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return v.equals(o);
        }

        //This is the title of the page that will apppear on the "tab"
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return page_titles[position];
        }

        //This is where all the magic happen
        public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null, false);
            View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, null, false);

            TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvdesc);

            title.setText(page_titles[position]);
            description.setText(desc[position]);

            //This is very important
            ( (ViewPager) pager ).addView( v, 0 );


            ( (ViewPager) pager ).addView( v2, 1 );
            return v;
        }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View pager, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) pager).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View view) {
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable p, ClassLoader c) {
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View view) {
    }

}


}
```

Is there any options to merge these classes? Make a switch for every page and which layout to charge? I'm newer in Android, can you help me to know how do it?

Comment: problem is you loose the ability to swipe on the map.  But having different fragments in a viewpager makes for a cool app.  You can use the viewpager technique somewhere else.  I'm using a viewpager in my settings dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the response.... :( I need to make a viewpager... is the requirement.
I´m trying to make a SupportMapFragment activity to bring me the map like an object and later make a public class titlepager extends FragmentActivity to get it

Comment: sounds tricky good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I've got three different fragments in a viewPager below.  The example below is a dialogFragment but that doesn't make a difference it could be an activity or a fragment.

```
public class FragmentPagerSupport extends DialogFragment implements
        OnPageChangeListener {

    static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public interface FragmentPageRefresh {
        void onRefresh();
    }

    MyAdapter mAdapter;

    ViewPager mPager;

    static FragmentPagerSupport newInstance(int startingPage) {
        FragmentPagerSupport f = new FragmentPagerSupport();
        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("startingPage", startingPage);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int startingPage = 0;
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        if (b != null) {
            startingPage = b.getInt("startingPage");
        }


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager, container);


        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this.getChildFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(startingPage);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        getDialog().setTitle("Best Rides Settings");
        return view;
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        // private Map<Integer, Fragment> mPageReferenceMap = new
        // HashMap<Integer, Fragment>();

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment ret = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                ret = SettingMap.newInstance(position);
                break;
            case 1:
                ret = SettingFollow.newInstance(position);
                break;
            case 2:
                ret = SettingRecord.newInstance(position);
                break;
            }
            // mPageReferenceMap.remove(position);
            // mPageReferenceMap.put(position, ret);
            return ret;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Map Type";
            case 1:
                return "Follow";
            case 2:
                return "Tracker";
            default:
                return "unused";
            }
        }
```

Here's how you do the ".newInstance" in the fragment.

```
    public class SettingFollow extends Fragment implements
        OnCheckedChangeListener,
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener,
        OnSeekBarChangeListener {


    public static Fragment newInstance(int position) {
        SettingFollow f = new SettingFollow();
        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", position);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }
 ...

}
```

simple layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->


<!-- Top-level content view for the simple fragment sample. -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/default_screen_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top" />
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

fire this beast up like this.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentPagerSupport editSettingsDialog = new FragmentPagerSupport();
            // MapSettings editSettingsDialog = new MapSettings();
            editSettingsDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
```